# Flat-UI - Navigation not collapsing properly. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest Twitter Bootstrap with Flat UI. I am trying to make a simple navbar that collapses when the screen gets too small. How can I fix this?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Only when I click the 'toggle navigation' button do my navigation items appear.

Here is my HTML for the navbar. It's the one copied directly from the Flat-UI components page:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, this is how I resolved this:

- Downloaded latest https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI
- Verified it was using Bootstrap 3 at /boostrap/css
- Copied all css to /vendor/assets/stylesheets
- Copied all javascript to /vendor/assets/javascripts
- Copied all images to /vendor/assets/images
- Copied all fonts to /vendor/assets/fonts
- Made my /assets/javascripts/application.css.scss look like

**application.css.scss**

```
*= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css

*= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/flat-ui.css

*= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/demo.css

*= require_self

*= require_tree .

*/
```

- Made my /assets/stylesheets/application.js look like

**application.js**

```
    //= require turbolinks

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-select.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-switch.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/flatui-checkbox.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/flatui-radio.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.tagsinput.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.placeholder.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.stacktable.js

    //= require ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/application.js

    //= require_tree .
```

- Added a bootstrap starter markup to layouts/application.html.haml

```
    !!!
    %html
      %head
        %meta{:name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"}
        %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'Work'
        %meta{:name => "description", :content => "#{content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : 'Work'}"}
        = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
        = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
        = csrf_meta_tags
      %body
        %nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{role: "navigation"}
          .container
            .navbar-header
              %button.navbar-toggle{"data-target" => ".navbar-ex1-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse", type: "button"}
                %span.sr-only Toggle navigation
                %span.icon-bar
                %span.icon-bar
                %span.icon-bar
              %a.navbar-brand{href: "index.php"} Start Bootstrap
            .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse
              %ul.nav.navbar-nav
                %li
                  %a{href: "#about"} About
                %li
                  %a{href: "#services"} Services
                %li
                  %a{href: "#contact"} Contact
        .container
          .row
            .col-lg-12
              = render 'layouts/messages'
              = yield
```

And I got something like

[image: Screenshot]

So, it's basically the *version mismatch problem that we had*

---

*P.S. Using references to files in vendor css/js files will probably break at production, so we'll need to update them perhaps to .scss and change for example `url:` to  `image-url:`, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you do @import 'bootstrap'; under app/assets/stylesheets? If not you need to create a file under app/assets/stylesheets called "customization.css.scss" then do @import 'bootstrap';

Comment: Hey Dylan. Did you do `@import 'bootstrap';` under app/assets/stylesheets? If not you need to create a file under app/assets/stylesheets called "customization.css.scss" then do `@import 'bootstrap';`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see to change is to move the .container inside of .navbar. Everything seems to be working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lk3AZ/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

If this still doesn't work, can you create a Fiddle with all of your code?